# rechart custom tooltip for label and not normal rechat Tooltip

Tags: reactjs, charts, customization, recharts

I'm building a radar chart with rechart, and I would like to add a custom tooltip, but not using the Tooltip component, as it only shows if I hover the points of the radarchart. I would like to add an info icon next to my label and then on hover of that icon a tooltip would show, like in the image below.

[image: Tool tip example]

I have a custom tick but I can't seem to be able to add much in there apart from tspan,  any idea on how I could I achieve what the image above is showing? Or if it's completely impossible

My custom tick is this

```
  function customTick({ payload, x, y, textAnchor, stroke, radius }) {
let numberX = x;
let numberY = y;
let textX = x;
let textY = y;
let score = 0;

if (payload.value === 'Talent Pipeline') {
  score = companyInfo.scoreSections.talentPipeline;
  numberY = y - 15;
  textY = y - 15;
}

if (payload.value === 'Retention') {
  score = companyInfo.scoreSections.retention;
  // numberX = x - 10;
  numberY = y + 35;

  textX = x - 20;
  textY = y - 15;
}

if (payload.value === 'Historical') {
  score = companyInfo.scoreSections.historical;
  // numberX = x + 5;
  numberY = y + 35;

  textX = x + 20;
  textY = y - 15;
}

if (payload.value === 'Access & Advancement') {
  score = companyInfo.scoreSections.accessAdvancement;
  numberX = x - 10;
  numberY = y + 20;

  textX = x + 70;
  textY = y + 20;
}

if (payload.value === 'Representation') {
  score = companyInfo.scoreSections.representation;

  numberX = x + 10;
  numberY = y + 20;

  textX = x - 20;
  textY = y + 20;
}

return (
  <g className="recharts-layer recharts-polar-angle-axis-tick">
    <text
      radius={radius}
      stroke={stroke}
      x={x}
      y={y}
      className="recharts-text recharts-polar-angle-axis-tick-value"
      textAnchor={textAnchor}
    >
      <tspan x={textX} y={textY} dy="0em" className="radarChart__labelText">
        {payload.value}
      </tspan>

      <tspan
        x={numberX}
        y={numberY - 20}
        dy="0em"
        className={`radarChart__labelNumber ${handleScoreColor(score)}`}
      >
        {score}
      </tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
);
```

}

Thank you in advance